# Unknown symbol in summation

Tags: summation

In this formula I am not sure what the symbol : means 
$$P_{cipher}(y) = \sum_{ \{k:y \in  c(k)\} }  P_{key}(k) P_{plaintext} d_k (y)$$

below the sigma

Where the notation P(x) represents the probability that the random variable X takes the value x. message space X = M key space K ciphertext space Y = C

Comment: This might be some of the worst notation I've ever seen.  Going to need a lot more context here.

Comment: @Randall its a crypto prof exercise for a university course, If you have something precise that you beleive is not accurate I will ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\{ \}$ - a set

$\in$ - "is an element of"

$\colon$ - "such that"

$\{k : y \in c(k)\}$ - "the set of all $k$ such that $y$ is in $c(k)$"

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you are summing over all keys $k$ as long as the key could potentially produce the ciphertext $y$ under the encryption. If it couldn't then there is no reason to consider it in your probability calculation.

Comment: if yo uwant answer the  exact same answer here and i will accept it : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52155/need-for-explanation-of-calculation-probability-of-appearance-of-a-certain-ciphe it is more relevant